# CIImage contentsOfUrl Failed to convert UIImage to PNG

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have a Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9.3) Playground with these contents, and it's failing in a non-obvious way.

```
import UIKit

let url: URL = URL(string: "https://placekitten.com/500/500")!
let image: CIImage = CIImage(contentsOf: url)!
```

The resulting error is `Failed to convert UIImage to PNG`. For completeness, the returned place kitten is a JPG image.

[image: Failed Playground]

Comment: this code works fine.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using @Kuldeep ?

Comment: xcode version is 9.2

Comment: If you want only `CIImage` than first of all try to create `UIImage` and that convert it to `CIImage`

Comment: Tried that, same failure mode, on Xcode 9.3

Comment: okay, let me check.

Comment: did the code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereas I cannot tell you the reason, for why your code does not work as expected, you can use the following workaround to retrieve a `CIImage` located at a specific URL as suggested in the comments:

```
import UIKit

let url: URL = URL(string: "https://placekitten.com/500/500")!
let image = UIImage.init(data: try! Data.init(contentsOf: url))!
let convertedImage = CIImage.init(image: image)
```

Don't forget to add adequate error handling. I left that out for the sake of simplicity